# Applying new map() function in JPQL query to retrieve result with column details

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to retrieve database sample results by applying JPQL query in spring boot microservice. I am using JPQL query for retrieving the resultset by column wise. When I am adding the required column , result only containing the value. There is no information of which is the column which belongs , Since I am taking this result from Angular 2 application. So I need the result as key-value pair.

After this when I am adding the new map() function with aliasing in JPQL query it is properly retrieving with columns.

**My first code is** ,

```
@Query("select u.username, p.pname  from Users u join u.priviJoin p where u.username = :uname")
    List<Users> findByUsername(@Param("uname") String uname);
```

**Result is - Not containing column info**

[["jacob","Admin"]]

**After adding map function , code is** ,

```
@Query("select  new Map(u.username as username , p.pname as pname) from Users u join u.priviJoin p where u.username = :uname")
    List<Users> findByUsername(@Param("uname") String uname);
```

**Result is** ,

[{"pname":"Admin","username":"jacob"}]

**Confusions -**

1. Why the column info getting only after adding map() fucntion in query ?
2. What is the use of map() function here ?
3. Why column not retrieving in first result?

**Note-:** The second query giving result with column only when there is a mapping/joining in tables. Otherwise first query is enough for result with column information. I am compelled to add map function only when there is a joining functionality.

Can anyone clarify my confusions please?

Comment: JPQL has no such "Map" constructor expression, so perhaps you need to edit your question and say that this is JPA provider specific, or Spring Data JPA specific, because it is not in the JPA spec

Comment: Ok..understood. I only a beginner in this. i thought that this is JPQL. So can I add this as HQL ? , Since JPQl is API standard and HQL is Hibernate implementation? Can I edit like this way ?

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr. Billy Frost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those three question are the same, the answer is:

**That is what the `Map` function is for.**

Normal query always return only the value selected in the form of a `List<Object[]>` and you have to access each column by position.

With the map function you get a `List<Map<String, Object>>` which can be accessed by name.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I understood that. But this is only happening when my table has a Join relation. My table has the one to many mapping. If I am not adding any joining/ mapping , then I can properly getting result by using first query. Problem is that this is happening only when I am adding mapping in tables. If there is no mapping first query is enough to retrieve result with column info. My confusion is that , why this happening for joined tables ?